# SQL query of multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem dealing with joins

This is my first table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `form` (
  `id_form` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nameform` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_form`)
)
```

The data in the table

```
INSERT INTO `form` (`id_form`, `nameform`) VALUES
  (1, 'Formulaire commun'),
  (2, 'Formulaire FCPR'),
  (3, 'Formulaire fonds d''amorçage'),
  (4, 'Formulaire FOPRODI'),
  (5, 'Formulaire ITP'),
  (6, 'Formulaire PASRI'),
  (7, 'Formulaire PCAM'),
  (8, 'Formulaire PIRD'),
  (9, 'Formulaire PMN'),
  (10, 'Formulaire PNRI'),
  (11, 'Formulaire PRF'),
  (12, 'Formulaire RIICTIC'),
  (13, 'Formulaire VRR');
```

My second table userdata:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `donnée_utilisateur` (
  `id_d` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_form` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_us` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_d`),
  KEY `id-form` (`id_form`),
  KEY `id-us` (`id_us`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=407 ;

ALTER TABLE `donnée_utilisateur`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fvdsvsd` FOREIGN KEY (`id_us`) REFERENCES `utilisateur` (`id_us`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `ssssssssssss` FOREIGN KEY (`id_form`) REFERENCES `form` (`id_form`);
```

The data in it:

```
INSERT INTO `donnée_utilisateur` (`id_d`,  `id_form`, `id_us`) VALUES
  (380, 2, 6),
  (381,  2, 6),
  (382,  3, 6),
  (383,  3, 6),
  (384,  4, 6),
  (385,  5, 6);
```

And finally the user table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `utilisateur` (
  `id_us` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_us`),

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

The data :

```
INSERT INTO `utilisateur` (`id_us`) VALUES
  (3),
  (6),
  (7);
```

What I want to do is to get the `id_form` which doesn't exist in `userdata` table for a specific user.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
SELECT f.id_form
FROM  `donnée_utilisateur` d
RIGHT JOIN `form` f ON f.id_form=d.id_form Where d.id_d IS NULL
```

This query leads to this result if we have that kind of data :

```
id_form
1
6
7 
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

This is the expected result and it's correct.  If I want this result for a specific user, I change it like this  :

```
SELECT f.id_form
FROM  `donnée_utilisateur` d
RIGHT JOIN `form` f ON f.id_form=d.id_form 
INNER JOIN  `utilisateur` u ON u.id_us=d.id_us Where d.id_d IS NULL AND id_us=6
```

I'm getting nothing or it should be like the result that I just wrote.
Let's take another example for `id_us=7`

```
SELECT f.id_form
FROM  `donnée_utilisateur` d
RIGHT JOIN `form` f ON f.id_form=d.id_form 
INNER JOIN  `utilisateur` u ON u.id_us=d.id_us Where d.id_d IS NULL AND u. id_us=7
```

This should result in all `id_form` from 1 to 12 because the user didn't insert any data.

Comment: And you did not get an error on `AND id_us=6`? You did not state the table alias in there.

Comment: Your right i got an error i just forgot to edited it

Comment: Upvote for one of the most thorough questions / detail/ information needed to address the question I've seen in awhile.

Comment: You sure that's mysql? `d''amorçage` is a syntax error. mysql uses `\'` to escape quotes, not `''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with a subselect

```
select id_form  from form where 
id_form not in (select distinct id_form from  donnée_utilisateur where id_us=6 )
```

Or RDBMS engine correctly

```
select id_form  from form where 
id_form not in (select  id_form from  donnée_utilisateur where id_us=6 )
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but i think this doesn t solve my user issue

Comment: I have slightly update teh answer with id_us = 6  ... i think the at least the first should be right .. why these don't sovel your issuse? .. please explain me ..

Comment: this has the same result for id_us=6 or 7 or even 12 am trying to get the values that doesn't exsit inside `donnée_utilisateur` your code has something like this as a result

Comment: id_form = 1,2,3,..,12

Comment: Based on the date you provided like sample the select  in update question must provide only the form_id in form that are not in donnée_utilisateur with id_us=6 .. if is not check your data or your schema

Comment: @Kamel Mili: This is the straight-forward query for what you describe. For user 6 you'd get 1,6,7,... and for user 7 you'd get 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ... i.e. the forms that are missing in donnée_utilisateur for the given user.

Comment: @scaisEdge: Remove `distinct` from your subquery. It's should be up to the DMBS to decide how to perform the `IN` clause optimally.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  .. yes .. should be the RDBMS but the disctinct ind this case if for an  educational ascpect .. is for expalin to the OP that the in is performed only on the single value aniway  ( the rdbms do the same result but in this manner the OP i hope understand better .. )  .. post the two query so the OP can test that give the same result  ..

Answer (score 3):

Right joins are very hard to read and thus prone to errors. Usually you'd start with the table you must get data from and then left outer join tables you might get data from.

Let's look at your query:

1. You right join after table `donnée_utilisateur`, so `donnée_utilisateur` gets outer joined to the other tables.
2. The other tables are `form` and `utilisateur`. You have no join criteria combining the two, so you cross join them, i.e. combine every `form` with every `utilisateur`.
3. So to this cross join product you outer join `donnée_utilisateur`.
4. `Where d.id_d IS NULL` makes this an anti join. A trick used to replace a mere `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` in DBMS that have weaknesses with these straight-forward methods. You use it to get all `form` / `utilisateur` combinations for which there is no entry in `donnée_utilisateur`. Probably many.
5. `Where id_us=6` further narrows the results. Unfortunately you forgot to use a qualifier. Is it `u.id_us` or `d.id_us`? The DBMS cannot know. Let's say it decides you mean `d.id_us`. That field is always null, because you just dismissed all matches. `d.id_us = 6` is never true, so all rows get discarded. Your result is empty. If the DBMS decided you mean `u.id_us`, you'd prabably get results, particularly the same `id_form` over and over.

You may want to add the qualifier `u`, but I suggest you rather re-write the whole query and use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`.

And what has `utilisateur` to do with your query anyway? I thought you where looking for forms for which not exists user 6 in `donnée_utilisateur`. Why join `utilisateur` at all? (And if you join it, you should probably outer join it to `donnée_utilisateur`.)

Comment: So your suggesting i don't use joins i use not in , not exist ??

Comment: Yes. Make it a habit to use `[NOT] IN/EXISTS` when checking whether data exists or not. Don't use the anti-join pattern if not forced to do so. Don't use right joins; when outer-joining use left joins.

Answer (score 1):

Thorsten was very good in his clarification, but did not provide the completed query to help you.  Your original right-join query was VERY close.  However, I have switched to a left-join as follows:

```
SELECT
      f.id_form,
      f.nameform
   from
      form f
         left join donnée_utilisateur d
            ON f.id_form = d.id_form 
            AND d.id_us = 6
   where 
      d.id_d IS NULL
```

So, I am starting with the FORM table to get the ID and the name.  No problem.  Now, your consideration that the form is not found within the secondary table, so that is a left-join on the form ID and looking for NULL in the where clause.  But this, by itself is qualifying a form for ANY user.  To finalize your need for a specific user, just add the AND clause to the secondary table so THAT portion remains as a left-join for the FORM AND specific user resulting in NULL for the d.id_d column